# Percona XtraDB Cluster Operator - mount additional storage (INFILE)

Tags: kubernetes, percona, persistent-volume-claims, percona-xtradb-cluster

We have Percona XtraDB Cluster Operator setup on Kubernetes. In main configuration of cluster we have set persistentVolumeClaim option for pxc and proxysql.

This is the query, we would like to execute on our Percona Cluster:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/cloud/percona-data/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE testTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, testcolumn);
```

File '/cloud/percona-data/test.csv' has to be available via local storage.

We tried hostPath option, but it seems to be not active, because persistentVolume is configured (is that true or my configuration is not valid?).

This is the part of cluster configuration:

```
volumeSpec:
  hostPath:
    path: /cloud/percona-data
    type: Directory
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 6Gi
```

Is there any way to mount additional storage to all pxc and proxysql pods?

**Install guide**
[Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://www.percona.com/doc/kubernetes-operator-for-pxc/kubernetes.html)

**Configuration files:**
[cr.yaml](https://pastebin.com/VKY4J8qF)
[operator.yaml](https://pastebin.com/u15Qu8dU)

Thanks all.

Comment: Please, share your yaml for pod, persistentVolume and persistentVolumeClaim so I can see the whole picture.

Comment: @mWatney i've added links to question

I've only copy original yaml config files from percona website and then edit some options. Pods, persistentVolumeClaims and persistentVolumes are created automatically by operator.

Comment: I tried many options like directly edit StatefulSet and add volumeMounts, also failed, because pods are managed by operator (i think)

Comment: *bump*, anyone?

Comment: @mWatney any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using NFS? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59647560/12153576).

Comment: @JakubSakač You can patch/edit statefulset by scaling down Operator to 0